# how to connect drop down list with button and php file with if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, button, hyperlink, dropdown

I'm new in php, and I need help. I have created drop down list, than I should hit submit button and it should run one of my php files that are in drop down list. (using if statement) I tried in this way:

```
<p>
What Genre you want?
  <select name="Ganre">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="FPS">FPS</option>
  <option value="JRPG">JRPG</option>
  <option value="RPG">RPG</option>
  <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
</select>

<?php if (Genre == "FPS"): ?>    

<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="FPS.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Submit">
</FORM>;

</p>
```

Comment: Hi, I would strongly recommend that you had a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better idea of how SO works and how to write your question so it's received the best possible way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get values in PHP by using PHP superglobal (POST/GET):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['Ganre'])){
    echo $_GET['Ganre'];
    // use your stuff that you want in IF condition.
}
?>
```

And if you need values in URL as sub string than you need to replace form method with `$_GET`:

Change:

```
<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="FPS.php">
```

With:

```
<form method="get" action="yourfilename.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your code like this:

```
<?php if (Genre == "FPS") { ?>
<form method="get" action="FPS.php">
<select name="Genre">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="FPS">FPS</option>
  <option value="JRPG">JRPG</option>
  <option value="RPG">RPG</option>
  <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
```